# How to achieve 1x writing speed for 4K encoding in ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Is it possible to encode 4K asset in 1x writing speed ?

Below are our encoding commands and details of CPU, source assets, and encoding command output:

**Encoding command**

```
ffmpeg -i 4K_Source.mp4 -c:v libx265 -preset ultrafast
    -x265-params fps=60:profile=main:min-keyint=60:crf=19 -vf "scale=3840:2160"
    -sc_threshold 0 4K_UF_3840x2160_CRF19.mp4
```

**Source Asset Details**

```
Overall bit rate mode      : Constant
Overall bit rate           : 51.6 Mb/s
Format                     : HEVC
Format/Info                : High Efficiency Video Coding
Format profile             : Main 10@L5.1@High
Duration                   : 1 min 33 s
Width                      : 3 840 pixels
Height                     : 2 160 pixels
Display aspect ratio       : 16:9
Frame rate                 : 59.940 (60000/1001) FPS
```

**CPU details**

```
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E7-8870 v3 @ 2.10GHz (144 core)
```

**FFMPEG command output**

```
ffmpeg version 3.2.4-static http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.1 (Debian 5.4.1-5) 20170205
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-5 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gray --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
[mpegts @ 0x3a2b600] start time for stream 1 is not set in estimate_timings_from_pts
[mpegts @ 0x3a2b600] Could not find codec parameters for stream 1 (Audio:  
aac ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 0 channels, fltp): unspecified sample rate
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize'   
options
Input #0, mpegts, from 'Samsung_SUHD_Colorful_Food.mp4':
  Duration: 00:01:33.11, start: 1.050044, bitrate: 52076 kb/s
  Program 1
    Stream #0:0[0x101]: Video: hevc (Main 10) ([36][0][0][0] / 0x0024), yuv420p10le(tv), 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 90k  
 tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x102](und): Audio: aac ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 0 channels, fltp
[libx265 @ 0x3a53d40] Unknown option: profile.
x265 [info]: HEVC encoder version 2.2+35-fe2f2dd96f8c
x265 [info]: build info [Linux][GCC 5.4.1][64 bit] 10bit
x265 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA3 LZCNT BMI2
x265 [info]: Main 10 profile, Level-5.1 (Main tier)
x265 [info]: Thread pool 0 using 64 threads on numa nodes 0,1,2,3
x265 [info]: Thread pool 1 using 64 threads on numa nodes 0,1,2,3
x265 [info]: Slices                              : 1
x265 [info]: frame threads / pool features       : 8 / wpp(68 rows)
x265 [info]: Coding QT: max CU size, min CU size : 32 / 16
x265 [info]: Residual QT: max TU size, max depth : 32 / 1 inter / 1 intra
x265 [info]: ME / range / subpel / merge         : dia / 57 / 0 / 2
x265 [info]: Keyframe min / max / scenecut / bias: 60 / 250 / 0 / 5.00
x265 [info]: Lookahead / bframes / badapt        : 5 / 3 / 0
x265 [info]: b-pyramid / weightp / weightb       : 1 / 0 / 0
x265 [info]: References / ref-limit  cu / depth  : 1 / off / off
x265 [info]: AQ: mode / str / qg-size / cu-tree  : 1 / 0.0 / 32 / 1
x265 [info]: Rate Control / qCompress            : CRF-19.0 / 0.60
x265 [info]: tools: rd=2 psy-rd=2.00 early-skip rskip tmvp fast-intra
x265 [info]: tools: strong-intra-smoothing lslices=8 deblock
Output #0, mp4, to 'Samsung_UF_3840x2160_CRF19.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (libx265) ([35][0][0][0] / 0x0023), yuv420p10le, 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 59.94 fps, 60k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.64.101 libx265
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (hevc (native) -> hevc (libx265))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 5581 fps= 20 q=-0.0 Lsize=  212585kB time=00:01:33.05
bitrate=18713.8kbits/s speed=0.336x
video:212514kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:2kB muxing overhead: 0.033184%
x265 [info]: frame I:     23, Avg QP:24.29  kb/s: 133747.47
x265 [info]: frame P:   1401, Avg QP:26.43  kb/s: 31994.19
x265 [info]: frame B:   4157, Avg QP:29.67  kb/s: 13602.20
x265 [info]: consecutive B-frames: 1.3% 1.4% 1.5% 95.9%
encoded 5581 frames in 276.59s (20.18 fps), 18714.28 kb/s, Avg QP:28.83
```

The encoding speed we get is 0.3x only. we are trying encode HEVC codec asset to HEVC codec itself with 4K resolution in 1x writing speed.

Are we missing any parameters in ffmpeg command which can tweak encoding speed?

Comment: Skip the scaler if the resolution remains the same. In any case, upgrade ffmpeg - your x265 build is old.

Comment: Stream copy the existing AAC audio with `-c:a copy` instead of re-encoding it.

Answer (score 6):

I believe you essentially want to perform encoding of a file that is 2:00 minutes long in a total duration of 2:00 minutes itself - or in other words to read input at the native frame rate.

If so; try and add a `-re` before/after (I don't remember) `-i` like this:

`ffmpeg -re -i 4K_Source.mp4 -c:v libx265 -preset ultrafast -x265-params fps=60:profile=main:min-keyint=60:crf=19 -vf "scale=3840:2160" -sc_threshold 0 4K_UF_3840x2160_CRF19.mp4`

Read more about `-re` [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide).